# Unable to concat two variables along with underscore for ansible hosts

Tags: jenkins, ansible, string-concatenation, hosts

Below is the command generated by [ansible plugin for Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Ansible+Plugin).

```
ansible-playbook /app/stop.yml -i /app/my-hosts -l test_west -e app_name=test -e environments=west -v
```

Here is my ansible inventory hosts file.

```
cat my-hosts
[test_west]
10.0.9.88
10.0.9.89
```

-l option helps match the ansible inventory host file 'test_west'

My question is ... what do I have to mention in the ansible playbook for the hosts ?

My playbook looks like below however this does not seem correct or needed as the hosts are match using the -l paramter passed to ansible:

```
---
- hosts: "{{ app_name + '_' + environments }}
```

Can you please suggest what should I set the hosts: to in my ansible playbook so it is the same as -l argument i.e 'test_west' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use: `- hosts: "{{ app_name }}_{{ environments }}"`

Sample output:

```
[root@greenhat-30 tests]$ ansible-playbook -i hosts test.yml -e app_name=test -e environments=west
 [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: test_west


PLAY [test_west] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

[http_offline@greenhat-30 tests]$
```

You can see the group selected is `PLAY [test_west]`.

Comment: It helps. Thank you !!